# Couldn't run a ffmpeg process by using supervisor

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, supervisord

This issue seems to be weird, at least for me.

I'm trying to run a ffmpeg process using the supervisor as follows:

```sh
[program:myprocessname]
command="/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i ..."
process_name=%(program_name)s
numprocs=1
umask=022
priority=999
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
startretries=3
exitcodes=0
stopsignal=TERM
stopwaitsecs=10
user=vagrant
```

This program never gets run, in spite of changing the command to the absolute path where the `FFmpeg` is located.

This is what I get (from log) when I try to run it:

```
{
    "description": "can't find command '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i 
 ...'",
    "exitstatus": 0,
    "group": "myprocessname",
    "logfile": "/var/log/supervisor/myprocessname-stdout---supervisor-oxWFk5.log",
    "name": "myprocessname",
    "now": 1554747933,
    "pid": 0,
    "spawnerr": "can't find command '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i ...'",
    "start": 1554747575,
    "state": 200,
    "statename": "FATAL",
    "stderr_logfile": "/var/log/supervisor/myprocessname-stderr---supervisor-WNmJv6.log",
    "stdout_logfile": "/var/log/supervisor/myprocessname-stdout---supervisor-oxWFk5.log",
    "stop": 0
}
```

It might be that FFmpeg spawns processes where the supervisor couldn't handle?

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by removing the quotes from the command

```sh
[program:myprogam]
command="/usr/bin/ffmpeg ... With qoutes"
...
```

Changed to:

```sh
[program:myprogam]
command=/usr/bin/ffmpeg ... No quotes
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Look for more information in the following logs:

"stderr_logfile": "`/var/log/supervisor/myprocessname-stderr---supervisor-WNmJv6.log`"

"stdout_logfile": "`/var/log/supervisor/myprocessname-stdout---supervisor-oxWFk5.log`"

It seems that `ffmpeg` is not installed in `/usr/bin`. Or not installed at all.